# Execute Shell for Salt in Jenkins with inconsistent results

Tags: shell, jenkins, salt-stack

I am trying to execute a shell command from Jenkins to do a Salt call. I am able to get the command to work without having parameters in.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo salt '*' test.ping
```

but when I execute with a parameter I get an error:

*[TestUpgrade] $ /bin/sh /tmp/hudson6841559319172934172.sh
ERROR: No return received
No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure*

The command looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo salt $Minion_Group test.ping
```

I am trying to insert '*' as the string parameter. 
When I echo the command, everything looks good.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to use SaltAPI instead. Jenkins has corresponding plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this is a quotation issue.

Salt doesn't interpret asterisk as a wildcard, instead, it tries to find `'*'` minion id. And you cannot remove single quotes as it would lead to wildcard expanding before `salt` command is run.

Try to set `$Minion_Group` to `*` and temporary disable glob expanding:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f
sudo salt ${Minion_Group} test.ping
set +f
```